# catch errors within generator and continue afterwards

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, iteration

I have an iterator which is supposed to run for several days. I want errors to be caught and reported, and then I want the iterator to continue. Or the whole process can start over.

Here's the function:

```
def get_units(self, scraper):
    units = scraper.get_units()
    i = 0
    while True:
        try:
            unit = units.next()
        except StopIteration:
            if i == 0:
                log.error("Scraper returned 0 units", {'scraper': scraper})
            break
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
            log.warning("Exception occurred in get_units", extra={'scraper': scraper, 'iteration': i})
        else:
            yield unit
        i += 1
```

Because `scraper` could be one of many variants of code, it can't be trusted and I don't want to handle the errors there.

But when an error occurs in `units.next()`, the whole thing stops. I suspect because an iterator throws a `StopIteration` when one of it's iterations fails.

Here's the output (only the last lines)

```
[2012-11-29 14:11:12 /home/amcat/amcat/scraping/scraper.py:135 DEBUG] Scraping unit <Element div at 0x4258c710>
[2012-11-29 14:11:13 /home/amcat/amcat/scraping/scraper.py:138 DEBUG] .. yields article
[2012-11-29 14:11:13 /home/amcat/amcat/scraping/scraper.py:138 DEBUG] .. yields article
[2012-11-29 14:11:13 /home/amcat/amcat/scraping/scraper.py:138 DEBUG] .. yields article
[2012-11-29 14:11:13 /home/amcat/amcat/scraping/scraper.py:138 DEBUG] .. yields article
[2012-11-29 14:11:13 /home/amcat/amcat/scraping/scraper.py:138 DEBUG] .. yields article
[2012-11-29 14:11:13 /home/amcat/amcat/scraping/scraper.py:138 DEBUG] .. yields article
[2012-11-29 14:11:13 /home/amcat/amcat/scraping/scraper.py:138 DEBUG] .. yields article
[2012-11-29 14:11:13 /home/amcat/amcat/scraping/scraper.py:138 DEBUG] .. yields article
[2012-11-29 14:11:13 /home/amcat/amcat/scraping/scraper.py:138 DEBUG] .. yields article
[2012-11-29 14:11:13 /home/amcat/amcat/scraping/scraper.py:138 DEBUG] .. yields article
[2012-11-29 14:11:13 /home/amcat/amcat/scraping/scraper.py:138 DEBUG] .. yields article Counter-Strike: Global Offensive Update Released
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amcat/amcat/scraping/controller.py", line 101, in get_units
    unit = units.next()
  File "/home/amcat/amcat/scraping/scraper.py", line 114, in get_units
    for unit in self._get_units():
  File "/home/amcat/scraping/games/steamcommunity.py", line 90, in _get_units
    app_doc = self.getdoc(url,urlencode(form))
  File "/home/amcat/amcat/scraping/scraper.py", line 231, in getdoc
    return self.opener.getdoc(url, encoding)
  File "/home/amcat/amcat/scraping/htmltools.py", line 54, in getdoc
    response = self.opener.open(url, encoding)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 406, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 444, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 527, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
[2012-11-29 14:11:14 /home/amcat/amcat/scraping/controller.py:110 WARNING] Exception occurred in get_units

...code ends...
```

So how can I prevent the iterating to stop when an error occurs?

EDIT: here's the code within get_units()

```
def get_units(self):
    """                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    Split the scraping job into a number of 'units' that can be processed independently                                                                                                                                                  
    of each other.                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

    @return: a sequence of arbitrary objects to be passed to scrape_unit                                                                                                                                                                 
    """
    self._initialize()
    for unit in self._get_units():
        yield unit
```

And here's a simplified _get_units():

```
INDEX_URL = "http://www.steamcommunity.com"

def _get_units(self):
  doc = self.getdoc(INDEX_URL)  #returns a lxml.etree document

  for a in doc.cssselect("div.discussion a"):
    link = a.get('href')
    yield link
```

EDIT: question followup: [Alter each for-loop in a function to have error handling executed automatically after each failed iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648200/alter-for-loops-to-have-continue-and-error-handling-executed-automatically-after)

Comment: By "when an error occurs in `get_units`", do you actually mean "when an error occurs in `unit.next()`"?

Comment: Please do `easy_install pep8`, and next time run `pep8 mysourcefile.py` and fix all problems before posting :) ...and read http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: I already fixed it. Also, never use `except:`—instead prefer `except Exception:`—otherwise you'll catch even stuff like `KeyboardInterrupt` so the user cannot quit the program with `Ctrl-C`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StopIteration` is raised by the `next()` method of a generator when there is no next item anymore. It has nothing to do with errors inside the generator/iterator.

Another thing to note is that, depending on the type of your iterator, it might not be able to resume after an exception. If the iterator is an object with a `next` method, it will work. However, if it's actually a generator, it won't.

As far as I can tell, this is the only reason why your iteration doesn't continue after an error from `units.next()`. I.e. `units.next()` fails, and the next time you call it, it's not able to resume and it says it's done by throwing a `StopIteration` exception.

Basically you'd have to show us the code inside `scraper.get_units()` for us to understand why the loop is not able to continue after an error inside a single iteration. If `get_units()` is implemented as a generator function, it's clear. If not, it might be something else that's preventing it from resuming.

**UPDATE:** explaining what a generator function is:

```
class Scraper(object):
    def get_units(self):
        for i in some_stuff:
            bla = do_some_processing()
            bla *= 2  # random stuff
            yield bla
```

Now, when you call `Scraper().get_units()`, instead of running the entire function, it returns a generator object. Calling `next()` on it, will take the execution to the first `yield`. Etc. Now if an error occurs ANYWHERE inside `get_units`, it will be tainted, so to say, and the next time you call `next()`, it will raise `StopIteration`, just as if it had run out of items to give you.

Reading of http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/ (and http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/) strongly recommended.

**UPDATE2:** A possible solution https://gist.github.com/4175802

Comment: code is incoming, but could you point me to an explanation of the difference too?

Comment: Well, there's my answer. thanks! 
I have close to 50 scrapers with generators, is there any way i could prevent having to rebuild them all?

Comment: Can you instead handle the errors right where they occur? I.e. inside the original generator? That way you can just hide any failed iterations from your wrapping `get_units()` function. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472786/continue-after-exception-raising-in-iterator-generator-in-python

Comment: Well, i could, but this would be hours of re-building all the functions. also it wouldn't be very DRY.

Comment: I'm sure there's a solution but we'd have to see more of your code. The solution probably involves a somewhat different approach altogether. For example, I can think of a wrapper function for calls inside a single iteration that turns exceptions into some returned values, which a downstream consumer can then decide to ignore. The `try-except` clause would then be just in one place—that wrapper function.

Comment: I've been thinking... since these functions contain a lot of loops, i'd ideally have a `continue` to be executed each time an error occurs, or a `return` when an error occurs outside of any loop (which is rare). I'm thinking about how i could implement this, but i wouldn't know just yet.

Comment: followup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648200/alter-for-loops-to-have-continue-and-error-handling-executed-automatically-after