# Alter each for-loop in a function to have error handling executed automatically after each failed iteration

Tags: python, for-loop

This question follows from [catch errors within generator and continue afterwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645112/catch-errors-within-generator-and-continue-afterwards)

I have about 50 similar (but different) functions which try to extract URLs and such from websites. Because each website is different, each function is different and because websites tend to change over time this code is messy and cannot be trusted.

Here's a simplified sample, or look at the sample in the first question

```
def _get_units(self):
    for list1 in self.get_list1():
        for list2 in self.get_list2(list1):
            for unit in list2:
                yield unit
```

What I want to do with this function is essentially change the behavior to match this:

```
def _get_units(self):
    for list1 in self.get_list1():
        try:                 
            for list2 in self.get_list2(list1):
                try:
                    for unit in list2:
                        try:
                            yield unit
                        except Exception as e:
                            log_exception(e)
                except Exception as e:
                    log_exception(e)
        except Exception as e:
            log_exception(e)
```

In short, I want to turn this

```
for x in list:
    do_stuff(x)
```

to this:

```
for x in list:
    try:
        do_stuff(x)
    except Exception as e:
        log_exception(e)
```

for each `for` in my functions.

But I want to do it in a pythonic way. I don't want `try:except` blocks scattered all over the 50 functions I need to alter. Is this possible? If so, how can I do it in the most DRY way, and can I do this with the error handling in one place?

**UPDATE:** this question formerly included a `continue` statement along with the logging, but as mgilson pointed out, this isn't necessary.

**UPDATE 2** with georgesl's answer the function becomes as follows:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def ErrorManaged():
    try:
        yield
    except Exception as e:
        log_exception(e)


def _get_units(self):
    for list1 in self.get_list1():
        with ErrorManaged():              
            for list2 in self.get_list2(list1):
                with ErrorManaged():
                    for unit in list2:
                        with ErrorManaged():
                            yield unit
```

which is a lot cleaner indeed. though, a mere decorator would be even better. can anyone tell me if this is possible? if not, i'll accept georgesl's answer.

Comment: Your innermost try-except is superfluous -- `yield` will not raise an exception.

Comment: What is the purpose of `continue` in your exception handling?  Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems unnecessary.  (note that if you can remove `continue`, this problem becomes **much easier**

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Since the second function will not be written but computed, i let the `try:except` be because it will be there regardless of the content of the loop.

Comment: @mgilson thinking of it... how did i not notice? if i `try:except` the whole block, i don't need `continue`... editing...

Comment: Is it possible to move some error handling into `get_list1` and `get_list2`?

Comment: nope, those are just meant to simplify, they don't even exist. and if they do, they're helper functions within the same file. not centered functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave this some more thought, the only solution to really suit my needs seems to be to modify the code itself. So here goes:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import inspect

@contextmanager
def ErrorManaged():
    try:
        yield
    except Exception as e:
        print e



def get_units():
    for x in range(-5,5):
        print(x)

        if x % 3 == 0:
            raise Exception("x nope")

        for y in range(-5,5):
            print("\t{}".format(y))

            if y % 3 == 0:
            raise Exception("y nope")

            for z in range(-5,5):
                print("\t\t{}".format(z))

                if z % 3 == 0:
                    raise Exception("z nope")


import re

def modify_get_units(get_units):    
    lines = inspect.getsourcelines(get_units)[0]
    add = "with ErrorManaged():\n"
    new = []
    tabsize = 0
    for c in lines[1]:
        if c == " ":
            tabsize += 1
        else:
            break

    count = 0
    for line in lines:
        new.append(" " * tabsize * count + line)
        m = re.match(r"^(\s+)for\s[()\w,]+\sin\s[^ :\n]+:\n$",line)
        if m:
            count += 1
            new.append(m.group(1) + " " * tabsize * count + add)

    return "".join(new)

oldfunc = inspect.getsource(get_units)
newfunc = modify_get_units(get_units)

#printing function bodies to show results

print(oldfunc)
print("\n\n\n")
print(newfunc)


#re-declare get_units
exec newfunc

#execute, but now now
#get_units()
```

**output:**

```
toon@ToonAlfrinkPC ~ $ python test.py
def get_units():
    for x in range(-5,5):
        print(x)

        if x % 3 == 0:
            raise Exception("x nope")

        for y in range(-5,5):
            print("\t{}".format(y))

            if y % 3 == 0:
                raise Exception("y nope")

            for z in range(-5,5):
                print("\t\t{}".format(z))

                if z % 3 == 0:
                    raise Exception("z nope")





def get_units():
    for x in range(-5,5):
        with ErrorManaged():
            print(x)

            if x % 3 == 0:
                raise Exception("x nope")

            for y in range(-5,5):
                with ErrorManaged():
                    print("\t{}".format(y))

                    if y % 3 == 0:
                        raise Exception("y nope")

                    for z in range(-5,5):
                        with ErrorManaged():
                            print("\t\t{}".format(z))

                            if z % 3 == 0:
                                raise Exception("z nope")
```

Thanks for helping me get there!

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use decorators or better, [the context manager](http://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) :

```
from contextlib import contextmanager


def HandleError(func):

    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):

        try:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception:
            print "Bug on node #", args[0]


    return wrapped

@contextmanager
def ErrorManaged():
    try:
        yield
    except Exception:
        print "Oh noes, the loop crashed"



@HandleError
def do_something(x):
    print x
    if x==5:
        raise('Boom !')




with ErrorManaged():
    for x in range(10):
        do_something(x)
        if x == 7 :
            raise('aaaah !')
```

Comment: not that i don't know google, but could you include a link to `contextmanager` documentation?

Comment: I was thinking about context managers as well, but you still end up repeating the `with ...` portion every time rather than decorating the functions which makes it automatic.

Comment: you're right @mgilson, maybe I can save some space using a generator, but I didn't succeed to make it work.

Comment: This looks good, but I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with the `with` statement yet. I've tried implementing this but i don't really get it. Could you please implement your answer in my function so i can see? and test?

Answer (score 2):

I might "decorate" the functions themselves.  Presumably you have them stored in a list or something if you're living by DRY principles:

```
def decorate_function(func):
    def decorated(x):
        try:
            return func(x)
        except Exception as e:
            log_error(e)
    return decorated
```

Now you can just decorate your functions with this and it will log your errors.  Note that this assumes that the `continue` statement above is unnecessary.  It looks like it isn't really used to me, but I might be missing something.

If the functions really don't return something, then you could return `True` or `False` depending on if you hit an exception.  You could use that to write your `continue` logic.  Something like:

```
if not decorated_function(x): continue
```

Comment: @StevenRumbalski -- But that's not what the code snipet above will do is it?  Each `for` encloses a single `try-except`.  So if you catch an error, you'll hit `except` and then `continue` which just continues the current loop.

Comment: which is what i want, but not how things are right now. Please note that the second code snippet is how i want the first code snippet to behave, it's not existing code.

Comment: @ToonAlfrink -- I understand that.  What I can't see is how your two examples relate to each other.  (the two versions are the version with `self...` where you `yield` a value compared to the version where you actually call a function.)