# How to catch an exception in the for loop iterator

Tags: python, exception

This is a `for` loop in Python:

```
for_stmt ::=  "for" target_list "in" expression_list ":" suite
```

Normally, when yielding a value from the `expression_list` raises an exception, the loop aborts.  Is there an elegant way (short of rewriting the loop using `while True` or something similar) to catch this exception and continue the loop?

Here is an example:

```
import csv

csv.field_size_limit(10)

reader = csv.reader(open('test.csv', 'r'))
for line in reader:
    print(line)
```

with this file:

```
foo,bar,baz
xxx,veryverylong,yyy
abc,def,ghi
```

This aborts at the second line.  I would like a way to skip or log the failing lines and continue.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472786/continue-after-exception-raising-in-iterator-generator-in-python, but I can't change the generator in this case.

Comment: Why not just make a generator that calls the other generator but with a `try/except`?

Comment: @MatthewAdams: That won't work.  Once a generator throws an exception it cannot be resumed.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski That's what I was thinking, but with `csv.reader`, it's not true (tried it myself).  It raises a `_csv.Error`, but another call to `next()` on the `reader` will then just return the next after the error inducing line, and it will continue through to `StopIteration` as normal.

Comment: can you clarify why try: print(line) except: continue does not work?

Comment: @mehtunguh The `raise` happens in `reader.next()`, essentially, which is called in the for loop itself.  `print` is after the fact, so `try/catch` around it won't work.

Comment: @sr2222 So then the question is: will it work with the generator Peter's using? I think that depends on how his original generator is implemented, but it probably will work.

Comment: Actually, it probably won't work; a generator created by a standard generator function or expression will not resume after raising. But it _may_ work, so it's definitely worth testing.

Comment: @MatthewAdams Nope, the loop breaks out at the first exception.  You'd have to wrap the whole loop in a `while True` of some sort, `try/except` the inner loop, and restart it with the same iterator on every exception.

Comment: See http://pastebin.com/nZsyVfpe for evidence that a generator function or generator expression will not resume iterating after an exception. Running in Python 2.6, 2.7, or 3.3, both versions `[1]` rather than `[1, 3]`.

Answer (score 50):

If your inner iterable can be continued after an exception, all you need to wrap it is a trivial generator:

```
def wrapper(gen):
  while True:
    try:
      yield next(gen)
    except StopIteration:
      break
    except Exception as e:
      print(e) # or whatever kind of logging you want
```

For example:

```
In [9]: list(wrapper(csv.reader(open('test.csv', 'r'))))
field larger than field limit (10)
Out[9]: [['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']]
```

On the other hand, if the inner iterator can't be continued after an exception, there's no way you can wrap it:

```
def raisinggenfunc():
    yield 1
    raise ValueError("spurious error")
    yield 3

In [11]: list(wrapper(raisinggenfunc()))
spurious error
Out[11]: [1]
```

Any generator created by calling a Python generator function or evaluating a generator expression will not be resumable.

In such a case, you need to find some way to create a new iterator that resumes iteration. For something like `csv.reader`, that would mean reading `n` lines from the file before wrapping it in a `csv.reader`. In other cases it might mean passing `n` to the constructor. In other cases—as with `raisinggenfunc` above, it's just not possible.

Comment: Your hypothetical here is moot, as we've already established that `csv.reader` is continuable.

Comment: Generalizing is rarely harmful.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `except StopIteration: break` instead of `raise`?

Comment: Beautiful! This helped me skip lines with bad encoding

Comment: Thank you -clever and well-explained! But it's a pity there isn't a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: What if I want to print out some attribute of the generator upon `Exception` - the most recent line, for debugging for example?

Answer (score 6):

You could wrap the reader in another iterator that then handles the exceptions however you please.

```
class ExceptionHandlingIterator(object):
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self._iter = iter(iterable)
        self.handlers = []
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        try:
            return self._iter.next()
        except StopIteration as e:
            raise e
        except Exception as e:
            for handler in self.handlers:
                handler(e)
            return self.next()

csv_reader = ExceptionHandlingIterator(csv.reader(open('test.csv', 'r'))
# attach handlers to the reader here
for line in csv_reader:
    print line
```

Comment: This won't work if the inner iterable can't be continued after an exception. (Try replacing `wrapper` with `ExceptionHandlingIterator` in http://pastebin.com/nZsyVfpe and you'll see that you still get `[1]` rather than `[1, 3]`.) And if the inner iterable *can* be continued, I don't think it adds anything to a simpler iterator.

Comment: But in the OP's question, the iterator can be continued after the exception, and he wants to be able to customize how exceptions are processed, using one or more exception handling rules.  This adds exactly that ability.  You could one-off the iterator/generator for each handler situation, but that's just duplicating code.

Comment: But you still don't need to build a custom iterator that does the exact same thing as a generator function. It requires more knowledge to write, it's easier to get wrong, and it has more boilerplate that gets in the way of reading it.

Comment: If you have more than 1 set of logging/handling that you want to implement in this same pattern, you end up with far more boilerplate as you have to repeat this logic in each case.  This separates the job of defining how you want to handle exceptions from the mechanics of iterating.  All a user of this has to know is the interface of an exception; all the details about iteration are hidden.

Comment: You could add the same `handler` callback to the generator; you still don't need to explicitly build a class that matches the iterator protocol just so it can do exactly the same thing as a generator.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that if you are using `csv.reader` in the for loop, then you can cover that with a try exception and the for loop will continue. Here's a sample:

```
reader=csv.reader
try:
   for row in reader:
      if row[0]=='type':
         datarows.append(row)
except: continue
```

If this code faces an internal error, it jumps to the except block and continues the iteration for the next row in the CSV file.

**update**: this gives an error now as pointed out in the comments although I have used it with success in older versions of 2.7

Comment: `SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop`  in both python 2.7 and 3.x

Comment: This seems to be a new error. I have used this with success in the past to pass over faulty rows.

Comment: Works for me in Python 3.6.9

Comment: So what's the answer in a post-3.6.9, 2023 world?

Answer (score 1):

Fairly certain that this is not possible in pure Python, unfortunately.

Observe the following code:

```
def testIter(n):
    count = 0
    while count<n:
        try:
            for i in xrange(count,n):
                if i == 3:
                    raise Exception("Asdfas")
                count = count + 1
                yield i
        except:
            continue
```

This outputs the following:

```
x = testIter(10)
x.next()  # 0
x.next()  # 1
x.next()  # 2
x.next()  # Exception: Asdfas
x.next()  # Exception: StopIteration
```

One would expect it to continue in a new iteration of the while loop, but it does not.

Some people indicate that csv.reader() continues on an error. I don't feel like making a test case for it, but if it does I suspect it's because it's implemented as a C module found [here](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Modules/_csv.c). My C isn't too sharp so I didn't delve into it too much, but suffice to say I don't think it's possible.

EDIT: I didn't answer your question directly. Do what abarnet says in the case of an iterator that can be resumed (that means it's a C iterator).

EDIT 2: actually not strictly true.

```
class myInformativeException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, count):
        self.count = count

def testIter(n):
    for i in xrange(n):
        if i==4:
            raise myInformativeException(i)
        yield i

def iterwrap(n):
    x = testIter(n)
    try:
        for i in x:
            yield i
    except myInformativeException as e:
        print "Error on ", e.count
```

This prints:

```
0
1
2
3
Error on 4
```

So, clearly it's possible if you are able to make an iterator after X elements. Let me know if you need a more complete example.

Comment: Your EDIT 2 version doesn't continue after the error, so what does that show?

Comment: How far into the iterator you got before there was an error. From this, ANOTHER wrapper function could theoretically make a new iterator continuing after that. In pure Python.

Comment: So the idea is to pass the "cursor" back to calling code using an Exception. Neat idea ^^

Comment: I think you misunderstood something.

Comment: This question is from 10 years ago, so that is probably true.